# Vector addition

Tags: vectors

I am studying vectors on my own and am struggling with this question.

I have tried sketching diagrams but cannot visualise the situation or solve the problem.

Given that  **HL** + **KN** = **KL** + **HM** show that the points M and N are coincident.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, which I shall try to follow in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\vec{HL}+\vec{KN}=\vec{KL}+\vec{HM}$, then:

$$\begin{array}{rl}\vec{HM}&=\vec{HL}+\vec{KN}-\vec{KL}\\&=\vec{HL}+\vec{LK}+\vec{KN}\\&=\vec{HN}\end{array}$$

and from $\vec{HM}=\vec{HN}$ you conclude $M=N$.

Answer (score 0):

Put the origin $O$ in your diagram, and remember that
$$\overrightarrow{HL} = \overrightarrow{OL}-\overrightarrow{OH}.$$
Now proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging the equation **HL** + **KN** = **KL** + **HM**:

**HL** + **KN** - **KL** = **HM**

Notice that -**KL** = **LK**, so we can say:

**HL** + **KN** + **LK** = **HM**

Now look at the diagram below:

[image]

In the diagram, we can deduce that **HL** + **KN** + **LK** = **HN**.

Since we know that **HL** + **KN** + **LK** = **HM** from the equation you provided, we know that **HM** = **HN**. Thus, M and N must be the same point.